# Installation of i386 Deb(Hangul 2008) into AMD64 architecture; dpkg/library error

Tags: 64-bit, dpkg, dependencies, libraries, shared-library

I'm using chrubuntu 12.04 LTS on acer chromebook c720.

As I'm korean, I'm trying to install 'Hangul 2008 Linux', Korean style 'MS-word' software made for linux users. Becuase it is only for i386 architecture with .rpm file I needed to convert those files into .deb files using alien command.

Installing this on my Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit in my Virtualbox went smoothly linking some lib* files from /usr/bin to usr/bin/i386....

But installation of this on my chrubuntu 64bit architecture stalls with some dependency error messages for two deb files.

As learned from other successor I ran 'apt-get install -f' or installing unfound lib* files but there are no dependency errors nor all lib files are installed already.
I think maybe the path those *.deb files point mismatches to where real lib files are in.

Please, Can any one help me for installing this program?

### Errors I got

```
user@chrubuntu:/media/user/USB DISK/Debs43bit-noscritps$ sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i haansoft-hwp7-plugin_7.5.6.482-4axDT3_i386.deb 
[sudo] password for user: 
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
(Reading database ... 196194 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace haansoft-hwp7-plugin 7.5.6.482-4axDT3 (using haansoft-hwp7-plugin_7.5.6.482-4axDT3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement haansoft-hwp7-plugin ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of haansoft-hwp7-plugin:
 haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libc6 (>= 2.1.3).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4).
haansoft-hwp7-plugin depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1).

dpkg: error processing haansoft-hwp7-plugin (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
haansoft-hwp7-plugin
user@chrubuntu:/media/user/USB DISK/Debs43bit-noscritps$
```

---

```
user@chrubuntu:/media/user/USB DISK/Debs43bit-noscritps$ sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i haansoft-common7-gst_7.5.6.536-5axDT3_i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
(Reading database ... 196194 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace haansoft-common7-gst 7.5.6.536-5axDT3 (using haansoft-common7-gst_7.5.6.536-5axDT3_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement haansoft-common7-gst ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of haansoft-common7-gst:
haansoft-common7-gst depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
haansoft-common7-gst depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
haansoft-common7-gst depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0).
haansoft-common7-gst depends on libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.0).
haansoft-common7-gst depends on libxml2 (>= 2.6.27).

dpkg: error processing haansoft-common7-gst (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
haansoft-common7-gst
```

---

What I have done.

```
root@chrubuntu:/home/user# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
root@chrubuntu:/home/user# apt-get install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@chrubuntu:/home/user# apt-get install libgcc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgcc1 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@chrubuntu:/home/user#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands,

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture --ignore-depends haansoft-hwp7-plugin_7.5.6.482-4axDT3_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture --ignore-depends haansoft-common7-gst_7.5.6.536-5axDT3_i386.deb
```

Comment: Thank you Avinash Raj, I added ingnore depends options and it forced to finish with that error.

Comment: I posted another question relayed after this one so, I would be glad if you have a time to look that also. :)